# Out of 237 Submitted pages only 7 indexed on webmaster tool

Tags: xml, magento, sitemap, google-search-console, indexed

I have submitted a sitemap some time ago on Google web master tool. but the strange thing there are only 7 web pages indexed. I thought the issue had to do with content duplication and `no-follow` links on pages in my `sitemap xml`. But there's no such.

I also tried to use the Fetch as Google feature for Submit to index. But still the number of indexed pages remains the same (7). Is there something I am missing here?

[image]

Kind Regards,
Mthe

Answer (score 1):

what is your site url?
i'm only guessing, but sometimes the index number on google search console / webmaster tools is not 100% accurate to real google search result

i'm not sure if it your site or not

but, try to type this on google : [site:www.easydry.com/austria/](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=site%3Awww.easydry.com%2Faustria%2F&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

^ see, there are more than 7 pages are indexed

Comment: Yes that is the correct url www.easydry.com/austria/.